# Can you use if statements to create variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make the switch from STATA to python for data analysis and I'm running into some hiccups that I'd like some help with. I am attempting to create a secondary variable based on some values in an original variable. I want to create a binary variable which identifies fall accidents (E-codes E880.xx -E888.xx) with a value of 1, and all other e-codes with a value of 0. in a list of ICD-9 codes with over 10,000 rows, so manual imputation isn't possible.

in STATA the code would look something like this

```
newvar= 0
replace newvar = 1 if ecode_variable == "E880"
replace newvar = 1 if ecode_variable == "E881"
etc
```

I tried a similar statement in python, but it's not working

```
data['ecode_fall'] = 1 if data['ecode'] == 'E880'
```

is this type of work possible in python? Is there a function in the numpy or pandas packages that could help with this.

I've also tried creating a dictionary variable which calls the fall injury codes 1 and applying it to the variable to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `if` first.

```
if data['ecode'] == 'E880': data['ecode_fall'] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can break it out into two lines like this:

```
if data['ecode'] == 'E880':
    data['ecode_fall'] = 1
```

or if you include an `else` statement you can have it in one line, similar syntax to your SATA code:

```
data['ecode_fall'] = 1 if data['ecode'] == 'E880' else None
```

Comment: The second one will assign `None` if the check fails.

Comment: I got this error message, I'm not sure how to interpret it "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: What was the code that got that error? Can you post it, the error traceback, and an example of `data` into the question?

Answer (score 0):

Following from the other answers, you can also check multiple values at once like so:

```
if data['ecode'] in ('E880', 'E881', ...):
    data['ecode_fall'] = 1
```

this leaves you having to only do one `if` statement per unique value of `data['ecode_fall']`.